# How to choose between nested elements using JQuery sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a collection of elements displayed in a collection of columns. I want the user to be able to click one of the "letter" class items and *if* they move their mouse vertically the small square they selected with move vertically and get sorted with the other small squares in the same column. If the user clicks a square and moves their mouse horizontally I want the *column* they clicked to move and get sorted with the other columns.

**JSfiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/ygoh9r78/

**code**

---

**HTML**

```
<div id="letter-containers">
            <ul class="letter-column">
                <li class="letter"></li>
                <li class="letter"></li>
                <li class="letter"></li>
                <li class="letter"></li>
                <li class="letter"></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="letter-column">
                <li class="letter"></li>
                <li class="letter"></li>
                <li class="letter"></li>
                <li class="letter"></li>
                <li class="letter"></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="letter-column">
                <li class="letter"></li>
                <li class="letter"></li>
                <li class="letter"></li>
                <li class="letter"></li>
                <li class="letter"></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="letter-column">
                <li class="letter"></li>
                <li class="letter"></li>
                <li class="letter"></li>
                <li class="letter"></li>
                <li class="letter"></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="letter-column">
                <li class="letter"></li>
                <li class="letter"></li>
                <li class="letter"></li>
                <li class="letter"></li>
                <li class="letter"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(".letter-column").sortable({
    axis: 'y'
});

$("#letter-containers").sortable({
    axis: 'x'
});
```